# How to diff command outputs in vim

Tags: shell, vim, diff, process-substitution

I tried `vim -d <(ffprobe one.mp4 2>&1) <(ffprobe two.mp4 2>&1)` to see the difference between the two videos' codecs etc., but vim doesn't show anything when it opens, just an empty split screen and this error

> ```
> "/dev/fd/12" [Permission Denied]
> ```

How can I conveniently use vim diff to compare two command outputs?

Comment: In zsh, using `=()` substitution worked. Not too clear why.

Comment: Works for me `vimdiff <( ffprobe 'Coasts.mp4' 2>&1 ) <( ffprobe 'Deserts and Grasslands.mp4' 2>&1 )`

Comment: @ChrisDavies oh, so looks like `vimdiff` but not `vim -d` works

Comment: `vim -d` and `vimdiff` both work for me here